# 404 error when filtering URL for key arguments with django rest framework generic views

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-generic-views

Basically I'm following a tutorial on how to filter for results through url regular expressions for my rest api. I'm looking to go to /api/v1/users/1/goals to get a list of the goals associated with a user. I've scoured the django rest framework docs and numerous tutorials and can't get this to work. I'm getting a 404 error that the url I'm requesting does not exist.

myapp.views.py

```
class ListCreateUser(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        serializer_class = serializers.UserSerializer


class RetrieveUpdateDestroyUser(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.UserSerializer


class ListCreateGoal(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Goal.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.GoalSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.filter(user_id=self.kwargs.get('user_pk'))


class RetrieveUpdateDestroyGoal(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Goal.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.GoalSerializer
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api/v1/users', include('dataStoreApp.urls', namespace='users')),

]
```

myapp.urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',
        views.ListCreateUser.as_view(),
        name='user_list'),

    url(r'(?P<pk>\d+)/$',
        views.RetrieveUpdateDestroyUser.as_view(),
        name='user_detail'),

    url('r^(?P<user_pk>\d+)/goals/$',
        views.ListCreateGoal.as_view(),
        name='goals_list'),

    url('r^(?P<user_pk>\d+)/goal/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',
        views.RetrieveUpdateDestroyGoal.as_view(),
        name='user_goal_detail'),

]
```

myapp.serializers.py

```
class GoalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Goal
        fields = ('id', 'user_id', 'name', 'amount',
                  'start_date', 'end_date', )


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'id', 'password')
        read_only_fields = ('id', )
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}
```

myapp.models.py

```
class Goal(models.Model):
    class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'Goals'
user_id = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1, 
on_delete=models.CASCADE)
NAME_CHOICES = (
    ("Goal 1", "Goal 1"),
    ("Goal 2", "Goal 2"),
    ("Goal 3", "Goal 3"),
)
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
amount = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)
start_date = models.DateField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)
end_date = models.DateField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)

def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Strangely enough, when I go to /api/v1/users/1/goal/1 I get the RetrieveUpdateDestoryUser view instead of the goal view returning the json information for user who's id=1

Comment: There's a typo in your urls.py you have `'r^(...` it should be `r'^(..`